# What does the output of fwf_empty mean?

Tags: r, readr

Could anyone help me to understand how to interpret the output of fwf_empty()? I don't know what the "begin" and "end" parts represent and also very confused about how to calculate the column width.
For example, I read:

```
massey <- readr_example("massey-rating.txt")
writeLines(read_lines(massey))
fwf_empty(massey)
```

And then get:

```
UCC PAY LAZ KPK  RT   COF BIH DII ENG ACU Rank Team            Conf
  1   1   1   1   1     1   1   1   1   1    1 Ohio St          B10 
  2   2   2   2   2     2   2   2   4   2    2 Oregon           P12 
  3   4   3   4   3     4   3   4   2   3    3 Alabama          SEC 
  4   3   4   3   4     3   5   3   3   4    4 TCU              B12 
  6   6   6   5   5     7   6   5   6  11    5 Michigan St      B10 
  7   7   7   6   7     6  11   8   7   8    6 Georgia          SEC 
  5   5   5   7   6     8   4   6   5   5    7 Florida St       ACC 
  8   8   9   9  10     5   7   7  10   7    8 Baylor           B12 
  9  11   8  13  11    11  12   9  14   9    9 Georgia Tech     ACC 
 13  10  13  11   8     9  10  11   9  10   10 Mississippi      SEC 
$begin
 [1]  0  4  8 12 17 22 26 30 34 38 42 47 63

$end
 [1]  3  7 11 15 19 25 29 33 37 41 46 59 NA

$col_names
 [1] "X1"  "X2"  "X3"  "X4"  "X5"  "X6"  "X7"  "X8"  "X9"  "X10" "X11"
[12] "X12" "X13"
```

I also searched the data but couldn't understand why R chooses the values shown above.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The function `read::fwf_empty()` will try to automatically parse a fixed width file. If you look at the `massey` text, you can see that the `begin` and `end` are the widths of the columns (plus the space).

For instance, look at the output of `readr::read_lines(readr::readr_example("massey-rating.txt"))`

```
# > readr::read_lines(readr::readr_example("massey-rating.txt"))
# [1] "UCC PAY LAZ KPK  RT   COF BIH DII ENG ACU Rank Team            Conf"                                                                                     
# [2] "  1   1   1   1   1     1   1   1   1   1    1 Ohio St          B10 "
# [3] "  2   2   2   2   2     2   2   2   4   2    2 Oregon           P12 "
# [4] "  3   4   3   4   3     4   3   4   2   3    3 Alabama          SEC "
# [5] "  4   3   4   3   4     3   5   3   3   4    4 TCU              B12 "
# [6] "  6   6   6   5   5     7   6   5   6  11    5 Michigan St      B10 "
# [7] "  7   7   7   6   7     6  11   8   7   8    6 Georgia          SEC "
# [8] "  5   5   5   7   6     8   4   6   5   5    7 Florida St       ACC "
# [9] "  8   8   9   9  10     5   7   7  10   7    8 Baylor           B12 "
# [10] "  9  11   8  13  11    11  12   9  14   9    9 Georgia Tech     ACC "
# [11] " 13  10  13  11   8     9  10  11   9  10   10 Mississippi      SEC "
```

It's just long text file. So `read::fwf_empty()` will try to figure out what should go in each column. Since the first few predicted column names are three letters, you see `start` and `end` separated by that width, plus the space (so four positions) -  (i.e. 0-3, 4-7, 8-11). Then once it hits `RT` (two letters) it goes from 17-19, and similarly for `Rank` (four letters) you see it goes from 42 - 46, and so on.

So it's telling you where the positions where it is defining the column, it does not have anything to do with the values in the data.